# Documentar codigo de Dart

Tags: dart

Intentando documentar codigo del lenguaje Dart, haciendo comentarios de algunas de las funciones y secciones que se tiene el codigo del proyecto, inclui algo de descripcion de las varibles
como resultado es esto, estara bien? alguna sugerencia

```
 Future getBannerBig() async {
    ///Utilizamos un bloque [try] el cual dentro contiene código que posiblemente resulte en una excepción o error.
    ///Try catch, instruccion para manejar errores que lleguen a ocurrir.
    try {
      ///Con un QuerySnapshot nos devuelve la consulta y se toma la referencia de la ubicación en Firebase.
      ///Si no se usa el [await] no se toma la referencia.
      final all = await _db.collection('banner_grande').getDocuments();
      print(all.documents);
      List<String> handles = new List();
      for (var item in all.documents) {
        ///La variable [_urlD] espera lo que se ha tomado como referencia.
        ///
        ///Pasaremos el valor por referencia a un método, lo que implica que el valor va a cambiar dentro del método.
        ///Luego con el metodo child devuelve todos los datos del elemento seleccionado.
        ///En donde muestra los datos llamados [name] que se encuentran dentro del documento de la coleccion [banner].
        String _urlD = await FirebaseStorage.instance
            .ref()
            .child("banner/${item.data['name']}")
            .getDownloadURL();
        handles.add(_urlD);
      }

      ///
      print(handles);

      ///El tipo de retorno no cambia, de esta manera vuelve a mostrar banner en ciclo.
      return handles;
    }

    ///Basicamente lo que hace [catch] es de que si se ha presentado alguna excepción en el codigo que esta en [try]
    ///lo captura, imprime el tipo de excepcion y se devuelve como [null], un vacio y no muestra los datos de la coleccion.
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return [];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece bastante fácil para cualquier programador que no entienda mucho de Dart, como yo.

Si tuviera que coger tu programa y empezar a programar estaría genial tener esos comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

**Doc comments vs. comentarios habituales**

En primer lugar, deberías plantearte si realmente necesitas incluir *doc comments* (///) en tu código o no. Por norma general, se utilizan este tipo de comentarios en la definición de clases, métodos, etc. de librerías públicas. De esta forma, el IDE puede identificar y mostrar información relevante (como descripciones y ejemplos de uso) al usuario de la librería cuando, por ejemplo, pasa el ratón por encima de una función. Además, los *doc comments* pueden ser utilizados para generar documentación de un proyecto con [dartdoc](https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc).

Si necesitas añadir comentarios a tu propio código también puedes utilizar *doc comments*, pero lo más habitual es utilizar comentarios normales (//).

**Qué comentar y qué no**

En segundo lugar, documentar cada línea de tu código no es una cosa necesariamente positiva. Por ejemplo, no es necesario comentar qué es lo que hace un bloque `try/catch`. Es un concepto ampliamente extendido en la mayoría de lenguajes modernos, y no aporta valor al usuario de tu código.

Además, deberías intentar que tu código sea lo más autoexplicativo posible, de forma que se minimice el número de comentarios. Esto se consigue utilizando nombres descriptivos para tus clases, funciones y variables; y evitando expresiones excesivamente complejas.

Fuente: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation